# wdenoise in Matlab- is this a 2D or a 3D filter?

Tags: matlab

I'm using the function wdenoise in matlab to denoise a stack of images stored as a 3D matrix [m x n x time]. I'm running wdenoise through the third dimension, time. It's working generally as expected, but when I view individual images from the stack, they appear to be spatially smoothed as well. Is this a byproduct of the temporal smoothing, or is there something in the function that is de-noising/smoothing in all dimensions?

```
my_matrix = [400x400x60];
my_denoised_matrix=zeros(size(my_matrix));



for i = 1:length(my_matrix)
    for j = 1:length(my_matrix)
        my_denoised_matrix(i,j,:) = wdenoise(squeeze(my_matrix(i,j,:)));
    end
end
```

Again, the temporal profile of each pixel is smoothed, which is what I expected. But why does the end result appear to be spatially smoothed as well?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you want to know what a filter does, apply it to a synthetic signal/image where you know what output to expect in different cases. Typically, `t=zeros(50,50,50);t(25,25,25)=1` is a good test case for linear filters (adjust sizes as needed). The result of filtering that is identical to the convolution kernel. You'll be able to see if it extends only along the 3rd dimension or along other dimensions too.

Answer (score 0):

They appear to be spatially smoothed as byproduct of the temporal smoothing.

The line `my_denoised_matrix(i,j,:) = wdenoise(squeeze(my_matrix(i,j,:)));` filters only in the third dimension (temporal smoothing).

You can verify there is no spatial filtering, by using the same image duplicated 60 times:

```
%Build "my_matrix" [400x400x60];
%Same image is duplicated 60 times.
I = imresize(im2double(imread('cameraman.tif')), [400, 400]);
my_matrix = repmat(I, 1, 1, 60);

my_denoised_matrix=zeros(size(my_matrix));

for i = 1:length(my_matrix)
    for j = 1:length(my_matrix)
        my_denoised_matrix(i,j,:) = wdenoise(squeeze(my_matrix(i,j,:)));
    end
end

%Check the difference between I and my_denoised_matrix:  
D = I - my_denoised_matrix;
max_abs_diff = max(abs(D(:)));
disp(['max_abs_diff = ', num2str(max_abs_diff)]);
```